# Uri problems

Tags: java, android, uri, http-get

So Im trying to create a url to use httpget on, to download the page source.
But Im having problems every time I run the app it says i have an illegal character in the string/uri.
Here's the code Ive tried.

```
String Search = "http://www.lala.com/";
```

also,

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.lala.com/");
```

and every time i try,

```
Uri search = new Uri("http://www.lala.com/");
```

I get "Cannot instantiate Uri".

Im not really sure what im doing wrong, also this is the code to get the page source.

```
try
          {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.lala.com/");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);


            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                str.append(line);
            }
            in.close();
            html = str.toString();   
           }
           catch (IOException e1)
           {

           }
```

Thanks for the help! ~ Tanner.

(lala.com is not the site I am using btw :P )

Comment: have you tried it without the backslash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because Uri is an abstract class and can't be instantiated.  Use this instead:

```
Uri search = Uri.parse("http://www.lala.com/");
```

If using HttpGet you will need to use the class java.net.URI instead of the android Uri.  A quick example:

```
try {
        URI search = new URI("http://www.lala.com/");
        new HttpGet(search);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried what you said and i get the error "The constructor HttpGet(Uri) is undefined" on this line,

Comment: oops! This line, HttpGet request = new HttpGet(search);

Comment: Sorry for taking slow long between replys. Anyway now i got it so there's no error's, but then i debug and ofc error! it says "java.lang.StringOutOfBoundsException"

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?  Please give the full stack trace and the relevant line if you would like help with that one.

Comment: Never mind I was actually getting that error from another piece of code, thank you for the help! Will accept answer!

Comment: I get the error cannot find symbol parse

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports. It might be because of a conflict between org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI and java.net.URI. I mean, you can do Uri search = new Uri("http://www.lala.com/") with the second one but with the first one, you would see the error you mentioned.